# Can't import pandas library

Tags: python, pandas, installation

When I try to import pandas I get the following error:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'maybe_downcast_numeric'

The full traceback down bellow:

```
 ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-2f8ac4e49576> in <module>()
----> 1 import pandas as pd
      2 # import time
      3 # import seaborn as sns
      4 # import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      5 # import datetime

D:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py in <module>()
     40 import pandas.core.config_init
     41 
---> 42 from pandas.core.api import *
     43 from pandas.core.sparse.api import *
     44 from pandas.stats.api import *

D:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\api.py in <module>()
      8 from pandas.core.dtypes.missing import isnull, notnull
      9 from pandas.core.categorical import Categorical
---> 10 from pandas.core.groupby import Grouper
     11 from pandas.io.formats.format import set_eng_float_format
     12 from pandas.core.index import (Index, CategoricalIndex, Int64Index,

D:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\__init__.py in <module>()
----> 1 from pandas.core.groupby.generic import DataFrameGroupBy, NamedAgg, SeriesGroupBy
      2 from pandas.core.groupby.groupby import GroupBy
      3 from pandas.core.groupby.grouper import Grouper
      4 
      5 __all__ = [

D:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\generic.py in <module>()
     34 from pandas.util._decorators import Appender, Substitution
     35 
---> 36 from pandas.core.dtypes.cast import (
     37     maybe_convert_objects,
     38     maybe_downcast_numeric,

ImportError: cannot import name 'maybe_downcast_numeric'
```

I didn't find any reference for this error. I did install it through Anaconda prompt. I believe, as I start tracing back my every step, I start having this problem after I installed `seaborn` with

```
conda install seaborn
```

and during the installation, without reading, was smashing the `Y` button, when it asked to install additional packages. I saw, it included pandas package too. Maybe this is the case ? Innitially, long time ago I guess I've installed `pandas`  with
`pip install pandas` 
How could I fix this error less painfully rather than reinstalling everything from scratch?

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm facing the same exact issue!

Comment: @Rika nope, so I just deleted whole environment and reinstalled everything one by one. That solved my issue

Comment: Thanks, I ended up getting this solved using some shananigans! I'll try to post what I did tonight maybe  this can be of any help to anyone in the future!